# Running Google App Engine from Eclipse on Ubuntu - Permission Denied in /opt

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu, pydev

I have Google App Engine installed under my /opt directory on Ubuntu.
After creating a sample Pydev Google App Engine project, I right click the src folder and try to run it.

I get the following error:

```
/opt/python2.5/bin/python2.5: can't open file '/opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Any ideas on how I can give eclipse permission to run this?

### EDIT 1 (Permissions)

```
drwxrwxr-x  8 root root     4096 2011-03-24 23:38 google_appengine
```

```
-r-xr-x---  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 appcfg.py
-r-xr-x---  1 root root   156 2011-03-24 23:38 BUGS
-r-xr-x---  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 bulkload_client.py
-r-xr-x---  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 bulkloader.py
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 demos
-r-xr-x---  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 dev_appserver.py
drwxrwxr-x  6 root root  4096 2011-04-22 22:13 google
drwxrwxr-x 12 root root  4096 2011-04-07 23:23 lib
-r-xr-x---  1 root root  5922 2011-03-24 23:38 LICENSE
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 new_project_template
-r-xr-x---  1 root root  6086 2011-03-24 23:38 README
-r-xr-x---  1 root root 44626 2011-03-24 23:38 RELEASE_NOTES
-r-xr-x---  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 remote_api_shell.py
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 templates
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 tools
-r-xr-x---  1 root root    59 2011-03-24 23:38 VERSION
```

### EDIT 2 (New permissions)

```
drwxrwxr-x  8 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 2011-04-22 20:15 ..
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 appcfg.py
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root   156 2011-03-24 23:38 BUGS
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 bulkload_client.py
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 bulkloader.py
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 demos
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 dev_appserver.py
drwxrwxr-x  6 root root  4096 2011-04-22 22:13 google
drwxrwxr-x 12 root root  4096 2011-04-07 23:23 lib
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root  5922 2011-03-24 23:38 LICENSE
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 new_project_template
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root  6086 2011-03-24 23:38 README
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root 44626 2011-03-24 23:38 RELEASE_NOTES
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root  2387 2011-03-24 23:38 remote_api_shell.py
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 templates
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 2011-03-24 23:38 tools
-r-xr-x--x  1 root root    59 2011-03-24 23:38 VERSION
```

Thanks

Comment: (My previous comments have evolved into an answer and have been deleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did a `chmod +x` on the main google_appengine directory but not recursively. Try `chmod -R +rx` on the directory.

Comment: Still no luck after doing this Justin. See new permissions in original question.

Comment: @Mcloving: a user needs read access to a file to execute it. (Voting to close as off-topic, as well; this has nothing to do with programming.)

Comment: @Wooble: It is pertinent to the setup of a mostly self-contained package that is the only feasible way to develop for GAE on Linux.  Google's instructions don't seem to include this step.

Comment: @Justin: simply un-tarring the SDK archive should set the appropriate permissions for almost everyone. If someone's broken their Linux installation such that it doesn't, that's really a question for the  Ask Ubuntu stackexchange site.